# net csharp LinkButton : Handling Server and Client side Events

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a **LinkButton** server control which have some attached method in OnClick Event in somepage.aspx.cs file throw it's Id (control), I want to add another Server side Event also to that LinkButton.

How to achieve that?

Edit:

on default.aspx.cs
this is a line of code which open a new window

```
lnlBtnProfile.Attributes.Add("onClick", "newwindow('" + acc.ProfileUrl + "','MyProfile');return false");
```

but I want another function to execute at same time.

Comment: Another server side or client side event?

Comment: Can you show us some code of what your intensions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a LinkButton with client side and server side event :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="myLink" 
   OnClientClick="alert('this is clientside event');" 
   OnClick="myLink_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is the server side event :

```
private void myLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Use **OnClientClick** for client side events and **OnClick** for server side events. But if you write an return false at OnClientClick, your control won't postback and your server side event won't be called.

**EDIT :** As I said, just remove the 'return false;' line, and your attached server side event will be called. Because the 'return false;' blocks the rest of your code including postback to server.

```
lnlBtnProfile.Attributes
  .Add("onClick", "newwindow('" + acc.ProfileUrl + "','MyProfile');");

lnlBtnProfile.Click += new EventHandler(lnlBtnProfile_Click);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple handlers for the server side click event the following way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    linkBtn.Click += new EventHandler(handler1);
    linkBtn.Click += new EventHandler(handler2);
}

protected void handler1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text += "33";
}
protected void handler2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text += "66";
}
```

This will result in firing both the handler1 and handler2 on a click of the given link button.

Comment: Seach for the term 'Multicast Delegate'. For example: http://www.netsplore.com/PublicPortal/blog.aspx?EntryID=9